# How can I resolve the unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install this package [LINK](https://github.com/MRPT/mrpt)

After trying to run command `sudo aptitude -f install libmrpt-dev mrpt-apps`

I get this:

```
libmrpt-dev is already installed at the requested version (1:1.9.9~snapshot20181219-1736-git-fbb837f9-bionic-1~ppa1~bionic)
libmrpt-dev is already installed at the requested version (1:1.9.9~snapshot20181219-1736-git-fbb837f9-bionic-1~ppa1~bionic)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfreenect0.5{a} libmrpt-hwdrivers1.9{ab} mrpt-apps mrpt-common{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 25.9 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmrpt-hwdrivers1.9 : Depends: libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is installed or
                                 libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.4.4) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libavformat57 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is installed
                        Depends: libavutil55 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is installed
                        Depends: libswscale4 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libmrpt-hwdrivers1.9 [Not Installed]               
2)     mrpt-apps [Not Installed]                          



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

I can see that depending packages have lower versions. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to follow the Install instructions! `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:joseluisblancoc/mrpt`; `sudo apt-get update`; `sudo apt-get install libmrpt-dev mrpt-apps`

Comment: @koni_raid I did follow the instructions

Comment: Looks like you don't have bionic-security or bionic-updates enabled. Check your sources. Alternately, perhaps you have had the problem for a longer time than you think.

Comment: @user535733 How can I add? I am using lubuntu and copied this into etc/apt/sources.list

`deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe and etc`


But got this error:
`E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]`

Comment: Comments are not intended for conversation, but to help you improve the question. If you want help fixing your sources, then please edit the complete list of your sources into the question.